# Calling va_arg fewer times than the number of arguments passed

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, variadic-functions

Is it undefined behavior if I call `va_arg` fewer times than the number of arguments passed in a variadic function?

For example:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
void foo(unsigned n, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    int bar = 0;

    va_start(ap, n);
    if (n) bar = va_arg(ap,int);
    // Do something with bar
}

int main() {
    foo(2, 3, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Will that program cause undefined behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your program *does* cause undefined behaviour, but not because of the way you're using `va_arg`.  That's just ignoring the extra argument, so it seems like a waste of typing to have included it.

What causes the undefined behaviour is that you haven't included `va_end` in that function.

From the spec (**7.15.1.1 The `va_arg` macro**):

> Each invocation of the **`va_arg`** macro modifies **`ap`** so that the values of successive arguments are returned in turn. ...If there is no actual next argument ... the behavior is undefined ...

and from **7.15.1.3 The `va_end` macro**:

> ...if the **`va_end`** macro is not invoked before the return, the behavior is undefined.

There is no mention of having to call `va_arg` a certain number of times.  As you can see, the `va_end` is important, though.

Answer (score 0):

`va_arg` is defined to return the arguments in the order that they were passed. If you call it fewer times than arguments, you will simply ignore any extra arguments.

Comment: This answer is sort of "half-correct".  While the number of calls to `va_arg` doesn't matter (as long as it's not too many), the OP's program *does* cause undefined behaviour.